# Any Python Library Produces Publication Style Regression Tables

Tags: python, latex, regression, stata, statsmodels

I've been using Python for regression analysis. After getting the regression results, I need to summarize all the results into one single table and convert them to LaTex (for publication). Is there any package that does this in Python? Something like [estout](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/esttab.html#esttab012) in Stata that gives the following table:

[image]

Comment: Any modern update to this question? There's summary2 which is still quite lacking.

Comment: @MatthewGunn This function is far from what you can do with Stata's estout package (or R's package). So what I ended up doing for my workflow is to call a user-defined function in Python that calls Stata to run a do-file in Terminal that run all the regressions and output the table.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23576328/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, there is `summary_col` in `statsmodels`; it doesn't have all the bells and whistles of `estout`, but it does have the basic functionality you are looking for (including export to LaTeX):

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.iolib.summary2 import summary_col

p['const'] = 1
reg0 = sm.OLS(p['p0'],p[['const','exmkt','smb','hml']]).fit()
reg1 = sm.OLS(p['p2'],p[['const','exmkt','smb','hml']]).fit()
reg2 = sm.OLS(p['p4'],p[['const','exmkt','smb','hml']]).fit()

print summary_col([reg0,reg1,reg2],stars=True,float_format='%0.2f')

===============================
         p0       p2      p4   
-------------------------------
const -1.03*** -0.01   0.62*** 
      (0.11)   (0.04)  (0.07)  
exmkt 1.28***  0.97*** 0.98*** 
       (0.02)   (0.01)  (0.01)  
smb   0.37***  0.28*** -0.14***
      (0.03)   (0.01)  (0.02)  
hml   0.77***  0.46*** 0.69*** 
      (0.04)   (0.01)  (0.02)  
===============================
Standard errors in parentheses.
* p<.1, ** p<.05, ***p<.01
```

Or here is a version where I add R-Squared and the number of observations:

```
print summary_col([reg0,reg1,reg2],stars=True,float_format='%0.2f',
                  info_dict={'N':lambda x: "{0:d}".format(int(x.nobs)),
                             'R2':lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x.rsquared)})

===============================
         p0       p2      p4   
-------------------------------
const -1.03*** -0.01   0.62*** 
      (0.11)   (0.04)  (0.07)  
exmkt 1.28***  0.97*** 0.98*** 
      (0.02)   (0.01)  (0.01)  
smb   0.37***  0.28*** -0.14***
      (0.03)   (0.01)  (0.02)  
hml   0.77***  0.46*** 0.69*** 
      (0.04)   (0.01)  (0.02)  
R2    0.86     0.95    0.88    
N     1044     1044    1044    
===============================
Standard errors in parentheses.
* p<.1, ** p<.05, ***p<.01
```

Another example, this time showing the use of the `model_names` option and regressions where the independent variables vary:

```
reg3 = sm.OLS(p['p4'],p[['const','exmkt']]).fit()
reg4 = sm.OLS(p['p4'],p[['const','exmkt','smb','hml']]).fit()
reg5 = sm.OLS(p['p4'],p[['const','exmkt','smb','hml','umd']]).fit()

print summary_col([reg3,reg4,reg5],stars=True,float_format='%0.2f',
                  model_names=['p4\n(0)','p4\n(1)','p4\n(2)'],
                  info_dict={'N':lambda x: "{0:d}".format(int(x.nobs)),
                             'R2':lambda x: "{:.2f}".format(x.rsquared)})

==============================
         p4      p4       p4  
        (0)     (1)      (2)  
------------------------------
const 0.66*** 0.62***  0.15***
      (0.10)  (0.07)   (0.04) 
exmkt 1.10*** 0.98***  1.08***
      (0.02)  (0.01)   (0.01) 
hml           0.69***  0.72***
              (0.02)   (0.01) 
smb           -0.14*** 0.07***
              (0.02)   (0.01) 
umd                    0.46***
                       (0.01) 
R2    0.78    0.88     0.96   
N     1044    1044     1044   
==============================
Standard errors in
parentheses.
* p<.1, ** p<.05, ***p<.01
```

To export to LaTeX use the `as_latex` method.

I could be wrong but I don't think an option for t-stats instead of standard errors (like in your example) is implemented.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to find this command on Google search? I spent half an hour looking for a command but could not find it. THanks!

Comment: I don't know ... I forget how I ran across it; Here is a link to the source file on github; it has a docstring: [summary2.py](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/iolib/summary2.py)

Comment: Great. It would be helpful for others if you include regressions with different explanatory variables.

Comment: Sure, added an example.

Comment: @KarlD. Great answer, it would be nice if pandas or statsmodels have a texreg or outreg2 like package for this. Academics use these a lot.

Comment: Is there a way to restrict which of the regressors will be included? I want to use the same approach as in the answer, but have many regressors whose coefficients I do not want to present. Didn't find in the documentation a way to do it

Comment: @splinter Not as near as I can tell. You could modify the function to do that pretty easily I think or post process the table it creates but it doesn't do it by default.

Comment: Yep, post processing is easy. It's disappointing though that python is so behind on this kind of stuff

Answer (score 4):

One alternative is [Stargazer](https://github.com/mwburke/stargazer). To get started quickly, refer to the [set of demo tables](https://github.com/mwburke/stargazer/blob/master/examples.ipynb) that Stargazer can produce.

Related posts include: [post1](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/32210/13935) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35051673/statsmodels-printing-summary-of-more-than-one-regression-models-together).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Karl D.'s great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576328/any-python-library-produces-publication-style-regression-tables/23576491#23576491) with the Statsmodels `as_latex` method, you can also check out the `pystout` [package](https://github.com/lucashusted/pystout).

```
!pip install pystout
```

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import statsmodels.api as sm
from pystout import pystout
```

```
data = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data.data, columns = data.feature_names)
df.columns = ['s_len', 's_w', 'p_len', 'p_w']

y = df['p_w']

X = df[['s_len', 's_w', 'p_len']]
m1 = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

X = df[['s_len', 's_w']]
m2 =  sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

X = df[['s_len']]
m3 =  sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

pystout(models=[m1, m2, m3],
        file='test_table.tex',
        addnotes=['Note above','Note below'],
        digits=2,
        endog_names=['petal width', 'petal width', 'petal width'],
        varlabels={'const':'Constant',
                   'displacement':'Disp','mpg':'MPG'},
        mgroups={'First Group':[1,2],'Second Group':3},
        modstat={'nobs':'Obs','rsquared_adj':'Adj. R\sym{2}','fvalue':'F-stat'}
        )
```

Don't spend hours like me trying to print out `pystout`. The LaTeX output is directly written on the `.tex` document you pass for `file`.

When compiled, the output looks like this:

[image: Some rendered LaTeX]