# statsmodels: printing summary of more than one regression models together

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

In the Python library `Statsmodels`, you can print out the regression results with `print(results.summary())`, how can I print out the summary of more than one regressions in one table, for better comparison?

A linear regression, code taken from `statsmodels` documentation:

```
nsample = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
X = np.column_stack((x, x**2))
beta = np.array([0.1, 10])
e = np.random.normal(size=nsample)
y = np.dot(X, beta) + e

model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results_noconstant = model.fit()
```

Then I add a constant to the model and run the regression again:

```
beta = np.array([1, 0.1, 10])
X = sm.add_constant(X)
y = np.dot(X, beta) + e 

model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results_withconstant = model.fit()
```

I'd like to see the summaries of `results_noconstant` and `results_withconstant` printed out in one table. This should be a very useful function, but I didn't find any instruction about this in the `statsmodels` documentation.

**EDIT**: The regression table I had in mind would be something like [this](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/esttab012c.png), I wonder whether there is ready-made functionality to do this.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23576328/any-python-library-produces-publication-style-regression-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there are number of ways to do that. Depends on what you can / want use to achieve that.

The starting point most likely will be the same:

`statsmodels` 'linear_model'`.fit()` returns [`RegressionResults`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults) class, which has `summary2()` method returning subclass with a few convenice methods.

One of which, for example, `.tables` returns `pandas.DataFrame`.

Here is how you could use this:

```
import pandas as pd 
results = {'Noconst':results_noconstant.summary2(), 
           'withcon':results_withconstant.summary2()}
df = pd.DataFrame({'Model':[], 'Param':[], 'Value':[]})
for mod in results.keys():
    for col in results[mod].tables[0].columns:
        if col % 2 == 0: 
            df = df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Model': [mod]*results[mod].tables[0][col].size,
                                         'Param':results[mod].tables[0][col].values, 
                                         'Value':results[mod].tables[0][col+1].values}))

print df
```

Which yields:

```
     Model                Param             Value
0  Noconst               Model:               OLS
1  Noconst  Dependent Variable:                 y
2  Noconst                Date:  2016-01-29 00:33
3  Noconst    No. Observations:               100
4  Noconst            Df Model:                 2
5  Noconst        Df Residuals:                98
6  Noconst           R-squared:             1.000
0  Noconst      Adj. R-squared:             1.000
1  Noconst                 AIC:          296.0102
2  Noconst                 BIC:          301.2205
3  Noconst      Log-Likelihood:           -146.01
4  Noconst         F-statistic:         9.182e+06
5  Noconst  Prob (F-statistic):         4.33e-259
6  Noconst               Scale:            1.1079
0  withcon               Model:               OLS
1  withcon  Dependent Variable:                 y
2  withcon                Date:  2016-01-29 00:33
3  withcon    No. Observations:               100
4  withcon            Df Model:                 2
5  withcon        Df Residuals:                97
6  withcon           R-squared:             1.000
0  withcon      Adj. R-squared:             1.000
1  withcon                 AIC:          297.8065
2  withcon                 BIC:          305.6220
3  withcon      Log-Likelihood:           -145.90
4  withcon         F-statistic:         4.071e+06
5  withcon  Prob (F-statistic):         1.55e-239
6  withcon               Scale:            1.1170
```

What you can do with this is only limited by your ability to use pandas - [powerful Python data analysis toolkit](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/basics.html).

Comment: Thanks, I thought `statsmodels` might have some ready-made functionality to make some regression tables, that's why I asked the question. The regression table I had in mind would be something like this [link](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/esttab012c.png) , but I guess I can twig the dataframe some how to make it similiar to this one. I'll add this link to the main question in case there is some ready way to make that kind of table.

Answer (score 9):

There is `summary_col`, which AFAIR is still missing from the documentation.

I have not really tried it out much, but I found a related example from an issue to remove some of the "nuisance" parameters.

```
"""
mailing list, and issue https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/1638
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
from statsmodels.iolib.summary2 import summary_col

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : list(string.ascii_uppercase)*10,
                   'B' : list(string.ascii_lowercase)*10,
                   'C' : np.random.randn(260),
                   'D' : np.random.normal(size=260),
                   'E' : np.random.random_integers(0,10,260)})

m1 = smf.ols('E ~ D',data=df).fit()
m2 = smf.ols('E ~ D + C',data=df).fit()
m3 = smf.ols('E ~ D + C + B',data=df).fit()
m4 = smf.ols('E ~ D + C + B + A',data=df).fit()

print(summary_col([m1,m2,m3,m4]))
```

There is still room for improvement.

Comment: Yeah, it's still far from pretty.. But glad to know someone is working on it!

Answer (score 6):

There is now a [Python version](https://github.com/mwburke/stargazer/) of the well known **stargazer** R package, which does exactly this.

See also this related question: https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/11774/24531

Comment: Good stuff. Worth noting that this currently only works for OLS

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible implementation:

```
import pandas as pd
def compare_statsmodels_ols(estimators, indice=0):
    if indice in [0, 2]:
        data_dict = {}
        if len(estimators) > 1:
            for k, est in estimators.iteritems():
                data_dict[k] = est.summary2().tables[indice].iloc[:, 1::2].stack().values

            index = estimators.popitem()[1].summary2().tables[indice].iloc[:, 0::2].stack().values
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)
            df.index = index
            return df

        else:
            raise 'waiting for a dictionnary for estimators parameter'
    else:
        raise 'Not working for the coeff table'   
estimators = {'m1': m1, 'm2': m2 }
compare_stats_models(estimators, 0)
```

with m1 and m2 being the prefitted models.
This solution works only for the first(indice=0) and third (indice=2) ols summary tables.

output :

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">  <thead>    <tr style="text-align: right;">      <th></th>      <th>m1</th>      <th>m2</th>    </tr>  </thead>  <tbody>    <tr>      <th>Model:</th>      <td>OLS</td>      <td>OLS</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>Adj. R-squared:</th>      <td>0.882</td>      <td>0.864</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>Dependent Variable:</th>      <td>Mpg</td>      <td>Mpg</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>AIC:</th>      <td>254.6367</td>      <td>273.3427</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>Date:</th>      <td>2016-12-14 16:28</td>      <td>2016-12-14 16:28</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>BIC:</th>      <td>389.3848</td>      <td>310.7728</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>No. Observations:</th>      <td>312</td>      <td>312</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>Log-Likelihood:</th>      <td>-91.318</td>      <td>-126.67</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>Df Model:</th>      <td>35</td>      <td>9</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>F-statistic:</th>      <td>67.12</td>      <td>220.9</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>Df Residuals:</th>      <td>276</td>      <td>302</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>Prob (F-statistic):</th>      <td>1.06e-114</td>      <td>3.28e-127</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>R-squared:</th>      <td>0.895</td>      <td>0.868</td>    </tr>    <tr>      <th>Scale:</th>      <td>0.11885</td>      <td>0.13624</td>    </tr>  </tbody></table>
```